# Chi Square Analysis - expected frequencies has a zero element at (0,). error

Tags: python, machine-learning, scipy, statistics, chi-squared

I am working on the data where I am trying to see the association between two variables and I used Chi-Square analysis in Scipy package in Python.

Here is the crosstab result of the two variables:

```
pd.crosstab(data['loan_default'],data['id_proofs'])
```

Result:

```
   id_proofs    2   3   4   5
  loan_default              
    0   167035  15232   273 3
    1   46354   4202    54  1
```

If I apply the Chi-Square on the same data, I see an error saying ValueError: The internally computed table of expected frequencies has a zero element at (0,).

Code:

```
from scipy.stats import chi2_contingency
stat,p,dof,expec = chi2_contingency(data['loan_default'],data['id_proofs'])
print(stat,p,dof,expec)
```

Error Report:

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-154-63c6f49aec48> in <module>()
      1 from scipy.stats import chi2_contingency
----> 2 stat,p,dof,expec = chi2_contingency(data['loan_default'],data['id_proofs'])
      3 print(stat,p,dof,expec)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/stats/contingency.py in chi2_contingency(observed, correction, lambda_)
    251         zeropos = list(zip(*np.where(expected == 0)))[0]
    252         raise ValueError("The internally computed table of expected "
--> 253                          "frequencies has a zero element at %s." % (zeropos,))
    254 
    255     # The degrees of freedom

ValueError: The internally computed table of expected frequencies has a zero element at (0,).
```

What could be the reasons for the issue? How can I overcome this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take another look at the docstring for [`chi2_contingency`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.chi2_contingency.html).  The first argument, `observed`, must be the contingency table.  You must compute the contingency table (like you did with `pd.crosstab(data['loan_default'],data['id_proofs'])`) and pass it to `chi2_contingency`.